# Too big DIV - width on desktop is too big

Tags: html, css, yii, view, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have update yii vendors and now have problem (before everything was ok). Check [this](http://stara.szukampracy.pl/aplikacja/post/173777) on mobile everything is ok but on desktop this second grey box div is too big

```
    <div class="box-header box-header-gray  box-header-gray-inner">
    <h3>Załączone pliki</h3>
</div>
```

First and third box are ok. Thanks for help/tips I have try add to box.scss max-width but nothing

Somewere not closed div tag?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the CSS for `form-group` like this:

```
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: before I have change it to inerhit and nothing, but thanks I will try auto

Answer (score 0):

Give `float: none;` to the div inside the field-applicationdetails-phone. i.e, div with class col-sm-12.